# Php upload issue with Centos

Tags: amazon-web-services, codeigniter, file-upload, centos

I'm uploading file more than `30MB` upto `2GB` but i can't upload it.AS if i upload files less than `30MB` its working fine but when i try to upload files more than `30MB` its not working. Also there is no any error too.

Here is php.ini file settings

```
post_max_size  = 2G
max_execution_time = 3600 
upload_max_filesize = 3600

memory_limit = 1024M
```

We are using AWS server with `Centos` as Os and we are using `codeigniter`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you upload a large size file, upload to S3 directly is recommended. You can do it by [generating S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-presigned-url.html) in EC2 then let the client upload through that URL. It will be much faster, consume much less EC2 bandwidth and cheaper storage cost.

---

#### For PHP config:

php doc: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize

`post_max_size`:

> Generally speaking, `memory_limit` should be larger than `post_max_size`.

`upload_max_filesize`:

> The maximum size of an uploaded file.
>   When an integer is used, the value is measured in bytes.

(Not sure why you can upload 30MB file if `upload_max_filesize` is 3600 bytes)

`memory_limit`

> This sets the maximum amount of memory in bytes that a script is allowed to allocate.

You can try the following:

```
post_max_size  = 2G
max_execution_time = 3600 
upload_max_filesize = 2G

memory_limit = 2560M
```

Comment: its not working and we are using `t2 small` instance of aws. and when i print `$_POST` its not getting that file also. Giving `502` error.  we are not getting that file in php file variable.

Comment: @raju_eww can you verify the php setting in phpinfo page?

Comment: From the phpinfo page, your `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` is `512M`